# preg_replace() only replace spaces, symbols with a hyphen

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How would I replace anything but letters and numbers with a hyphen? This would be for a slug URL where a person would type in the string they would like for their URL. The problem I’m having is people inputting symbols and many spaces which make the URL invalid.

Also, what would be a good resource to test this so that I don’t have to ask again? Thanks.

Comment: wouldnt urlencode just replace spaces with pluses? i'm not sure what it would do with symbols

Comment: it will. The problem you described in the question is "people inputing symbols and many spaces which makes the url invalid". `urlencode` will make any input to be a valid url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
$input_url = "This is only an example: do you like it?";
$slug_url = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-", $input_url);
print($slug_url);
```

will output

> `This-is-only-an-example--do-you-like-it-`

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/132977)

Comment: so this just accepts letters and numbers right? anything else gets replaced with a hypen

Comment: Exactly. The regular expression `"/[a-zA-Z0-9]/"` matches a letter or a number. On the other hand, since the caret sign negates a character class, the regular expression `"/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/"` matches any character apart from a letter or a number. Here the function [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) matches each instance of such non-alphanumeric character in the variable `$input_url` and replaces it with a hyphen. The result of this replacement is stored in the variable `$slug_url`.

Comment: What about `www.my_beautiful.url.whatever` ? It'll become `www-my-beautiful-url-whatever`.